# Score only takes into account last answer

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
random_words = ['michael ', 'is', 'cool', 'avyn','tooburt','mooburt','myself','jack','rahim']
import random

i = 0
while i < 5:
    score = 0
    random_word = random.choice(random_words)
    word = input(random_word + '  ')
    if random_word == word:
        score += 1
    else:
        score -= 1
    i += 1
print('you scored ' + str(score))
```

When I print the score its always either -1 or 1, how do I keep track of the score properly

Answer (score 2):

> *When I print the score its always either -1 or 1*[...]

This happens because `score` is reinitialised inside the loop at the start of each iteration.

Move it outside like this:

```
score = 0
while i < 5:
    ...
```